# Different P-values using cor.test and rcorr

Tags: r, correlation

Can someone help explain why P-values are different when comparing results using cor.test() and rcorr ? 
Level of significance changes quite a lot. Which results should I report/trust?

Thank you in advance.

/Tine

```
##########################################################################################################

> ### ONE CORRELATION AT THE TIME 
> ### CORRELATIONS WITH NEGATIVE AFFECTIVITY
> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$detach_pid) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$detach_pid
t = 16.206, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3174279 0.3983797
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.3585777 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$antag_pid) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$antag_pid
t = 8.744, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1579925 0.2470461
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.2029389 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$disin_pid) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$disin_pid
t = 11.775, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2251995 0.3113720
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.2688236 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$psycho_pid) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$psycho_pid
t = 22.134, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4273650 0.5002246
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.4645807 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$pid_total) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$pid_total
t = 36.247, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6241087 0.6775899
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.6516584 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$mean_negaff) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$mean_negaff
t = 10.68, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2012531 0.2885424
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.2453951 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$mean_posaff) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$mean_posaff
t = -9.6417, df = 1780, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2664647 -0.1781943
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.2227861 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$log.negaff_MSSD) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$log.negaff_MSSD
t = 6.6581, df = 1780, p-value = 0.00000000003684
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1102457 0.2008643
sample estimates:
     cor 
0.155883 

> cor.test(dat$na_pid,dat$log.posaff_MSSD) ### Significant

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dat$na_pid and dat$log.posaff_MSSD
t = 4.563, df = 1780, p-value = 0.000005388
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.06139719 0.15319620
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.1075259 


RESULTS USING RCORR (MATRIX OF CORRELATIONS - results reported below are limited to correlations with dat$na_pid)

mycor <- rcorr(as.matrix(x), type="pearson")    

            na_pid  

detach_pid  0,36**
antag_pid   0,2 ns
disin_pid   0,27*
psycho_pid  0,46***
pid_total   0,65***
mean_negaff 0,25*
mean_posaff -0,22*
log.negaff_MSSD 0,16 ns 
log.posaff_MSSD 0,11 ns
```

Comment: I don't think either of these cor methods adjust the p-values, so perhaps the difference is due to how missing data are handled -- although the correlations are the same¬. How does `rcorr` compare if you go through the correlation calculations one at a time as you did for `cor.test`? (ps some weird formatting of the cor.test pvalues )

Comment: ... actually I can't reproduce the differences you see using data with missing. Can you provide a sample of data where you can reproduce this please?

Comment: what package is `rcorr` in ... ? `Hmisc` ? Can we have a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, turning parameter  "exact=FALSE" in the cor.test() function when using spearman method, gives you exactly the same p-value as in the rcorr()

from the ?cor.test()
*exact

a logical indicating whether an exact p-value should be computed. Used for Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho. See ‘Details’ for the meaning of NULL (the default).*